# Filemaker: Set field default value to 1

Tags: filemaker

This might be a very stupid question but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I want to create a field in my table called "One" and it's value for all records in the table needs to be 1. 
E.G.

Field1 One
A       1
B       1
C       1
.
.
.

I set the field to a number and tried the auto enter data and typed 1 in the data field but it's not updating the values.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, Auto Enter applies to when the record is first created. One can do various other options, but this is the basic use of Auto Enter on a field. You set the value to be auto-entered in the field's options panel under Manage Database; a fixed value, calculated value and so on. This works on all versions of FileMaker.

That said, if this is to be a static value of 1 for all records, you might want to look into a calculation field with a result of 1 and possibly using global storage. This will not work if you need the user to be able to change the value.

Comment: Andreas is correct, I would only add that it will only work for the new records, but the existing records will not be updated. I suggest you select the field, use "Records" menu > "Replace Field Contents" and set it to 1